# Adding a Period to a Joda Interval

Tags: java, jodatime

Quick question:

I´m having an Interval of one day:

```
Interval interval = new LocalDate().toInterval(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
```

Suppose I want to add one day at the beginning and one day at the end.
Right now I use the methods `withDurationBeforeEnd` and `withDurationAfterStart` which don´t really fit to my use case. Am I missing something? I was looking for some API like `Interval.addPeriod(Period period);`

Or am I completely wrong and should use something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Interval newInterval = new Interval(oldInterval.getStart().minusDays(1), oldInterval.getEnd().plusDays(1));
```

Comment: Thank you. I still think that the API should provide something like the DateTime methods for Interval.

Comment: I agree. It would be more handy and make the code more readable.